# Cannot catch ImageMagick Image constructor exception

Tags: c++, imagemagick

I have the following code, trying to load an image. But the Image constructor throws exception and I cannot catch it.

```
      try {
        Magick::Blob blob(&input_buffer_[0], input_buffer_.size());
        Magick::Image image(blob);
        int w = image.columns();
        int h = image.rows();
        input_mat_.create(h, w, CV_8UC3);
        image.write(0, 0, w, h, "BGR", Magick::CharPixel, input_mat_.data);
      } catch (...) {
        return false;
      }
```

```
#0  0x00007f9808d8a617 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007f9808d8bd08 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007f9808d83586 in __assert_fail_base () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00007f9808d83632 in __assert_fail () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007f97f833badd in LockSemaphoreInfo (semaphore_info=<optimized out>) at MagickCore/semaphore.c:294
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "LockSemaphoreInfo"
#5  0x00007f981fdacaa8 in Magick::throwException (exception_=exception_@entry=0x7f9278009aa0, quiet_=<optimized out>) at Magick++/lib/Exception.cpp:846
        q = 0x0
        message = {static npos = <optimized out>, _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
            _M_p = 0x7f927803aba8 "nginx"}}
        p = <optimized out>
        nestedException = 0x0
        severity = <optimized out>
        index = <optimized out>
#6  0x00007f981fdba21d in Magick::Image::read (this=0x7f97da6211b0, image=<optimized out>, exceptionInfo=0x7f9278009aa0) at Magick++/lib/Image.cpp:5047
No locals.
#7  0x00007f981fdba37f in Magick::Image::read (this=<optimized out>, blob_=...) at Magick++/lib/Image.cpp:3982
        newImage = <optimized out>
        exceptionInfo = <optimized out>
#8  0x00007f981fdba3c9 in Magick::Image::Image (this=0x7f97da6211b0, blob_=...) at Magick++/lib/Image.cpp:89
No locals.
```

ImageMagick version: 7.Q16HDRI

Comment: The stack trace (which should be text, not an image) says it fails an assertion and calls `abort`.

Comment: At a guess you're missing a `InitializeMagick` call. Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Alan's comments are correct. The `LockSemaphoreInfo` suggests that ImageMagick was not initialized before reading an image. Add the following at start of the program.

```cpp
int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    InitializeMagick(*argv); // <= Here
```